# QR Code Scanner result can't be click

Tags: android, generator, qr-code, barcode-scanner, android-studio-3.0

I got a problem with my scanner app that I just build using android-studio 3.0. When it scanning, the result url can't be click.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
    Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
    alert1.show();

    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}}
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: what does mean result not clicked.Looks like you just showing an Alert dialog and nothing else.

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail, I guess you want make Dialog message Clickable

Comment: @PankajKantPatel I want to makes the result message is clickable

Comment: @ZaidMirza Yes, in my app I can only shown the message, but I can't click on the url. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your text linkify, please try below code. I have not tested it but it should work

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
// Linkify the message
    final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(rawResult.getText());
    Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);

    Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
    Log.v("TAG", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
    builder.setMessage(s);
    AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
    alert1.show();

    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the respond. I already tried the code, but it shows error like this:
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

Comment: error you are telling is unrelated to change in answer

Comment: I got a log that said "cannot resolve symbol 'SpannableString'". Same goes to linkify.

Comment: you have to Import class, Alt+Enter. These are very basic

Comment: Nevermind its my RAM. But I already test the code, the result is still the same sir. I can't click on the result link. It didn't direct me to the link url from the result.